# Cannot install PyMySQL locally within a virtual environment [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: macos, permissions, pip, virtualenv, pymysql

I'm trying to safely install `PyMySQL`. I've read many good arguments about why `sudo pip install` should be avoided, but sometimes it just seems impossible to get away from.

Is there a way to install `PyMySQL` locally in OSX without using `sudo`?

```
(VirtualEnv) : ^.^ :pip install --no-cache-dir --user PyMySQL
Collecting PyMySQL
  Downloading PyMySQL-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 1.8MB/s 
Installing collected packages: PyMySQL
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 247, in move_wheel_files
    prefix=prefix,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/locations.py", line 153, in distutils_scheme
    i.finalize_options()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 346, in finalize_options
    self.create_home_path()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 565, in create_home_path
    os.makedirs(path, 0700)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/TomNason/Library/Python/2.7'
```

Comment: So what are the permissions of the `/Users/TomNason/Library/Python/2.7` dir? What does `ls -l` show?

Comment: My guess is that you have already borked your user dir by using `sudo` so the root user now owns the user dir. This is why you shouldn't use `sudo` if you don't precisely understand what the command does.

Comment: `: ^.^ :ls -l /Users/TomNason/Library/Python/2.7/`
`ls: /Users/TomNason/Library/Python/2.7/: Permission denied` But why doesnt `pip` install to the virtual env specific instance of python 2.7? if i take of the `--user` option the same error and path appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install within a virtual env run this command.

`pip install --install-option="--prefix=/Users/TomNason/VirtualEnv/lib/python2.7" PyMySQL`

Generally- if you cannot install PyMySQL with pip inside a virtual environment (even if you are using the `--user` option) you can try...

`pip install --install-option="--prefix=PATH_TO_YOUR_VIRTUAL_ENV_DIR/lib/PYTHON_VERSION" PyMySQL`

This is still a curious situation for me. Any comments on why I would have to explicitely state my python directory are welcome. I thought that the reason for using a virtual environment was that pip will always choose to install there.